# Bugs in hypergeometric functions with negative integer lower parameters

Tags: bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

If you were to evaluate these expressions, *Mathematica* returns the value shown.

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{-6/2, -(6 - 1)/2}, {-(6 - 1)}, 1]           = 1/32

HypergeometricPFQ[{-n/2, -(n - 1)/2}, {-(n - 1)}, 1] /. n -> 6 = 1/64
```

Obviously these shouldn't be different.  The former should be correct.  Any insight as to why the latter is off by a factor of 2?

**Edit**

This evaluation seems to be correct

```
FunctionExpand[ Hypergeometric2F1[a, a/2 + 1, a/2, z]]// Simplify
```

> ```
> (1 - z)^(-1 - a) (1 + z)
> ```

```
With[{a = -2}, (1 - z)^(-1 - a) (1 + z)]
```

> ```
> (1 - z) (1 + z)
> ```

However here the result is different

```
With[{a = -2}, Hypergeometric2F1[a, a/2 + 1, a/2, z]]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Comment: It's a bug. Please report it to support :)

Comment: While you're reporting the bug you might consider mentioning that `Hypergeometric2F1` has the same issue:  `Hypergeometric2F1[-n/2, -(n - 1)/2, -(n - 1), 1] /. n -> 6` and `Hypergeometric2F1[-6/2, -(6 - 1)/2, -(6 - 1), 1]`.

Comment: The symbolic result prior to substitution is `2^(-n)`. This appears to agree with a [Wikipedia article]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Solutions_at_the_singular_points) (see "Special values at z = 1") and with [the functions.wolfram.com page](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/02/)

Comment: I have emailed this issue to support@wolfram.com and mentioned that `Hypergeometric2F1` has the same behavior. Hopefully they'll get to the bottom of it.  Thanks.

Comment: The former result is indeed correct, due to the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html). However, consider also the following evaluations: `With[{n = 6, h = 1*^-11, prec = 35}, N[{HypergeometricPFQ[{-(n + h)/2, -((n + h) - 1)/2}, {-((n + h) - 1)}, 1], HypergeometricPFQ[{-(n - h)/2, -((n - h) - 1)/2}, {-((n - h) - 1)}, 1], HypergeometricPFQ[{-(n + I h)/2, -((n + I h) - 1)/2}, {-((n + I h) - 1)}, 1], HypergeometricPFQ[{-(n - I h)/2, -((n - I h) - 1)/2}, {-((n - I h) - 1)}, 1]}, prec]]` (adjust `h` and `prec` as needed). "Obviously" isn't quite so.

Comment: In general, you get anomalies of this sort when the denominator parameter(s) of a hypergeometric function is a negative integer.

Comment: I was aware that some strange behavior might occur with the lower parameters being negative integers, but I didn't expect the function to be discontinuous.  Most texts try to get around these issues with a limiting argument, however, It certainly seems that the limit as h approaches zero that @J.M. is investigating above is not equal to the evaluation when h=0 (at least according to Mathematica.)  Interesting.